# Strange chracters in google maps API using java WebView

Tags: java, html, google-maps

**EDIT:**
I think I found the problem, I test the application in a window with java 7 and runs fine, no weird symbols and run the application on two different macs with java 8 and fail. I don't believe is the version because java it's supposed to run on any platform equally any theory.

**RE:EDIT:**
Is the OS!!!!! I just check, in a Windows with java 8 and worked, has to do with the encoding what can I do?? :'(. (I use macOS)

Maybe is only the JavaFX version and could save an old version of JavaFX in the app but don't know how to do that help, please.

**END EDIT**

I've made a desktop java application using WebView in JavaFX and make my own HTML page and everything worked fine, but suddenly the characters fails and I don't think is the HTML because I put an H1 and look fine but the google maps don't.

The HTML works fine in a browser but fails in java!.

Also, I erase the cookies.

Here is a screenshot [image: Screenshot]

Here is the HTML most copy paste from google api:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta >
    <title> "Vista de Clientes" </title>

    <style> 
    #map {
        height: 100%;
    }
    html, body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

  .controls {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 32px;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }

  #pac-input {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 300px;
  }

  #pac-input:focus {
  border-color: #4d90fe;
  }

  .pac-container {
  font-family: Roboto;
  }

  #type-selector {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4d90fe;
  padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
  }

  #type-selector label {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
  }
  #target {
  width: 345px;
  }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

  <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
  <h1> hola </h1>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEYISGOOD&libraries=places"></script>

  <script>



  // object for the stores
  var GreenCircle = {
  path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
  fillColor: 'Lime',
  fillOpacity: 1,
  scale: 10,
  strokeColor: 'green',
  strokeWeight: 1
  }; 

  // google map instance
  var map;
  var markers = [];

  // function for the initialization
  function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 12,
  center: {lat: 21.8857199, lng: -102.3613399}
  });

  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
  map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
  searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
  });


  searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
  var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

  if (places.length == 0) {
  return;
  }


  // Clear out the old markers.
  markers.forEach(function(marker) {
  marker.setMap(null);
  });
  markers = [];

  // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  places.forEach(function(place) {
  if (!place.geometry) {
  console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
  return;
  }

  var icon = {
  url: place.icon,
  size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
  origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
  anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
  scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
  };

  // Create a marker for each place.
  markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
  map: map,
  icon: icon,
  title: place.name,
  position: place.geometry.location,
  draggable: true
  }));

  if (place.geometry.viewport) {
  // Only geocodes have viewport.
  bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
  } else {
  bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
  }
  });
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
  }); 
  }

    initMap();

    function setMarker(latvar, lngvar, labels){
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
  position: { lat: latvar, lng: lngvar},
  map: map,
  label: labels || "",
  tittle: labels,
  icon: GreenCircle
  });
    }

  function setSelfMarker(Geojson)
  {
  map.data.addGeoJson( JSON.parse(Geojson) );
  }

  function setPosition(lat, lng)
  {
  map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng( lat, lng ) );
  }

    </script>


  </body>
  </html>
```

I load the code using:

```
 String webPage = this.getFileSrc("VistaClientes.html");
  webEngine.loadContent( webPage);
```

Is a string containing the full html.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?  I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that there is a bug in the JavaFX webview on Mac.  It tries to load some fonts locally and is disallowed.  You can workaround this for Google maps by adding the following CSS directive to your `<style>` tag.

```
.gm-style-mtc > div, .gm-style > div, .gm-style-cc > div, .gm-style {font-family:sans-serif !important;}
```

Comment: Has this bug already been reported to Oracle? I have the same problem and I would like that to be fixed rather than worked arround.

Comment: I have submitted the bug to Oracle.  Doesn't look like it had been previously submitted.

Comment: Could you please provide the JIRA bug id here so that I can track the bug?

Comment: Here is the bug report http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8175802

Comment: Is there any chance that this will be backported to 8?